# GCP Pubsub get the delivery attempts of a message on pull

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am receiving data from GCP pub/sub using a pull subscription.
I don't get any `delivery_attempts` field.
I saw it here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-dead-letter-delivery-attempt

Also, when tried to move to ASYNC - I got this field as null.

using latest pyhton SDK:
on sync I get this object:
`pubsub_v1.types.PubsubMessage`
which has no delivery_attempts.

on Async I get this:
`pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message`
but with an empty delivery_attempts field.

could it be related to the fact I have no Dead letter policy set?
I don't want one and prefer to keep working synchronously.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#track-delivery-attempts), the delivery attempts field is only populated when a dead-letter topic is set.

When using unary pull, the delivery attempt count is in each [`ReceivedMessage`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.ReceivedMessage) that comes back in the list in the [`PullResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.PullResponse).